# Check argument error text

Tags: ruby, rspec

Using rspec how do I check what an argument's error text is?

I have a method where if you supply an zero to it, an ArgumentError should be raised.

```
if amount_paid <= 0
   raise ArgumentError, 'Please insert Money'
end
```

The rspec code I have to check this is:

```
lambda {@method.check_money("Cola","0.00")}.should raise_exception ArgumentError
```

This test passes. When I supply the method with zero the argument error is raised. However how do I also check the text of the argument error? I have different argument errors in my code and I want to ensure that it is the correct one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The RSpec docs on matching errors](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher#match-message-with-a-string) have you covered.  Their example:

```
expect { raise StandardError, 'this message exactly' }.to raise_error('this message exactly')
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. So I changed my code to: `@method.check_money("Cool Cola","0.00").expect { raise ArgumentError, 'Please insert Money'}.to raise_error('Please insert Money')` However I now get an error message when I run the tests - `ArgumentError: Please insert Money./money.rb:19:in money'./spec/money_spec.rb:17:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`  - I also tried using Standard error but same issue. Any idea what is causing this? Works fine when I use lambda.

Comment: I suspect you may wish to explicitly name the exception class: `...to raise_error(ArgumentError, 'Please insert Money'`

Comment: Yep, got it sorted. Used the following `expect @method.check_money("Coca Cola", "0.00")}.to raise_error ("Please insert Money")`